# Change font and size in database field

Tags: ms-word, mailmerge, docx-mailmerge

I'm trying to mailmerge from word referencing to excel as database. However, I'm not exactly sure how I can change the font and the size of the field. e.g. I would like to change the font of [Person First Name] to font Arial with size 8. Kindly advice.

{DATABASE \d "{FILENAME \p}/../personnel.xlsx" \s " SELECT [Person First Name], [Person Last Name], [ID], [Title] FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE [ID] = {MERGEFIELD ID} ORDER BY [Title] " \l "15" \b "49" \h}

Comment: Database fields don't have fonts or a font size.

Comment: You would need to apply the formatting post-merge. For code to automate that, see for example: https://www.msofficeforums.com/151721-post27.html

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps will explore how VBA can help on this mailmerge.